# Who is the most powerful in Dragon Ball?

Tags: dragon-ball-series

Who is supposed to be the highest-power character in the *Dragon Ball* series? Is it Lord Beerus, Gogeta SS4, or somebody else?

Comment: Ok this is an opinionated question. But has been answered appropriately due to the info we currently have.

Comment: This question is fine to leave open, it can be answered without speculation.

Comment: Right now there is an objetive answer which is Zeno

Comment: Gogeta no matter what state would be weaker than vegetto, because the potala gives a much bigger power boost than a normal fusion.

Comment: Updated: [The strongest character in each Dragon Ball series](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/45044/the-strongest-character-in-each-dragon-ball-series)

Answer (score 10):

The most powerful character in the *Dragon Ball* universe, currently, is [Whis, Beerus' assistant](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Whis).

[image: Whis, standing next to Beerus]

This is stated in [an interview with Akira Toriyama](http://www.kanzenshuu.com/translations/battle-gods-animanga-akira-toriyama/), the creator of *Dragon Ball*:

> I suppose if Beerus’ strength is a 10, [Super Saiyan] God would be right about 6. [...] Incidentally, I guess Whis would be about a 15.

Comment: Damn, you beat me to it be a few seconds. Was about to press 'Post your answer' :p

Comment: Btw, Beerus said that Whis was the strongest only in the 7th universe (out of 12). There might be someone even stronger then him out there, that hasn't been revealed yet.

Comment: @PeterRaeves Yeah, that's why I was sure to add "currently." I expect more powerful beings to exist and be revealed in the future.

Comment: Please tell me if we compare whis with godgeta ss4. Who would be more stronger? Thanks in advance...

Comment: @AdityaGupta Whis.

Answer (score 0):

In an interview with Akira Toriyama, he states that Whis is the most powerful character.

To be honest, in my opinion, Goku is the strongest due to the fact that his power has no limits.  He has seven super saiyan forms, and currently, it is SUPER SAIYAN GOD 2 (-sweatdrops- Seriously?). He also has plot shields, and the trope DeathIsCheap.